# MariaDB get first and last record of the month - nested query

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and I have these kind of data:

[image]

I have also data for March and I am using this query to select distinct Months from the database:

```
select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(DT,'%m-%Y')) AS singleMonth FROM myTable
```

[image]

I want to be able to select FIRST and LAST record of P2 column for every month. How it is possible using the query above for getting all distinct months and also getting first record for the month and last?

Example what the query should return look-like:

[image]

Comment: I don't see what your results have to do with the sample data.

Comment: If you use MariaDB, please say "MariaDB" in your tags and question title (I have edited this). MariaDB has diverged from MySQL enough that we should consider it a different product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select year(dt), month(dt),
       min(case when seqnumn_asc = 1 then p2 end) as first_p2,
       min(case when seqnumn_desc = 1 then p2 end) as last_p2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(dt), month(dt) order by dt asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by year(dt), month(dt) order by dt desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by year(dt), month(dt);
```